# Modify variable in child process

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
 int x = 10;
 pid_t p = fork(), t = fork(), s = fork();
 printf("PID = %d -> pai: %d -> x = %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), x);
 return 0;
}
```

I'm really new to coding and been trying to do some exercises and there's this one where I can't do it

> "The proposed code generates a creation of 8 processes in all, where 7 of them are considered child processes.
> Change the formatting code as each of the child processes increases the variable  by 2 (two)
> units."

Thanks in advance, even you if just took your time to read it!

Comment: Please, add your understanding on the subject (what have you thought and tried, how it failed, how you understand the error msgs, etc.). The idea here is to help you understand, not to blindly solve problems for you.

Comment: There are several rather advanced concepts involved in this code. I don't think an analysis of this program is something suitable for "really new to coding" as you are introducing yourself.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you know how to detect whether you're in a child process or not? Do you know how to increase `x` by 2?

Answer (score 1):

From the `fork()` man page:

> RETURN VALUE
> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set  appropri‐
> ately.

Thus, you shoud check in each case wether you're in the parent or the child process, and proceed accordingly.

Hope this helps!